# How to make shell script executable after decompress without chmod

Tags: linux, shell

I am studying linux, and I have to make all shell scripts executable by this command:

```
find ./ -name "*.sh" -exec chmod u+x {} \;
```

But when I download Logstash.tar.gz and extract it to /opt, all shell scripts were executable, no chmod needed. And /opt is not in $PATH.

```
echo $PATH

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

How do I build an app like logstash works?

**===updated test steps for verification===**

```
mkdir testtar && cd testtar   
## create a executable script
echo test_with_x >> test_with_x.sh   
chmod u+x test_with_x.sh   
## create a not executable script
echo test_without_x >> test_without_x.sh   
cd ..    
## compress with gzip
tar -zcvf testtar.tar.gz ./testtar

mkdir testextract     
mv testtar.tar.gz ./testextract    
cd ./testextract    
tar -zxvf testtar.tar.gz   
## decompressed and see a executable and not executable script
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logstash tar bundle might have been created with executable permissions on all scripts. It should be the reason why it works fine after extracting without using `chmod u+x` command. If you also create a tar bundle with executable scripts, you should also get executable scripts after decompressing without using `chmod u+x`.

If you want your shell scripts to be executed without using `chmod u+x`, provide your shell script as an argument to your shell interpreter.

For e.g,

```
bash MyScript.sh
sh MyScript.sh
ksh MyScript.sh
```

Comment: Thanks, works as your explain, updated my test process on question page.

Answer (score 0):

You have two solution:

- Add `/opt` to the `PATH`:

  ```
  export PATH=${PATH}:/opt
  ```
- call `logstash` with full path:

  ```
  /opt/<anywhere.it.may.be>/logstash
  ```